# if a test case throws an exception (@expectedException) how to finish that method correctly?

Tags: phpunit

I have a test case:

```
/**
 * @expectedException Exception
 */
public function testDie()
{
    saveSomething();
    doOp();
    doOp(); // here the exception triggers
    restoreSomething(); // this line wont be executed, still I need it
}
```

something needs to be set and restore, but I cant restore because of the exception. How to dodge it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Catch the expected exception, and fail the test if no exception is caught.

However, having a necessary state restoration within a test function is bad practice.  Put the save in a setUp() function and the restore in a tearDown() function instead.

Comment: that OK, but that saving-restoring isnt needed always